# VBA Hide/Unhide Rows based on specific answers

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to hide/unhide rows based on specific cell values. So far my code works and is below: 
However, I am also trying to show rows between the "yes" "no" rows. for instance, row 11-15 begins as shown. Row 15 has "yes" or "no" answers. After choosing "yes", I need to show 16-20. but as of now, I can only show 20 (column 8 is the selection for yes/no and column 11 is the offset and column 12 currently contains the number to skip to... so row 15 column 12 contains "20"... but I need it to be 16-20). How do I solve this? Thank you

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Count > 1 Then

For Each cel In Target
       Call Worksheet_Change(cel)
       Next cel
End If
If Target.Column = 8 Then

   If LCase(Target.Value) = LCase(Target.Offset(, 3)) Then
   Cells(Target.Offset(, 4), 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
Else

   Cells(Target.Offset(, 4), 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True

End If:  End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to using a loop. What you want to do is hide each row in a loop, for example this loop will hide Rows 1-3

```
For i=1 to 3
    Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
Next
```

If I understnad your setup correctly column 8 contains "yes/no". Column 11 contains a row offset to start (un)hiding rows. Column 12 tells where to stop (un)hiding rows.

I will use the following notation to indicate a cell address *(row, column)*

Back to your example if *(15,8)* says "yes" then you unhide rows 16,17,18,19,**20**. This means *(15,11)* would contain **1** since the offset to get to row 16 is the current_row + 1, where current row is *15* cell *(15,12)* contains **20** since it is the last row to skip to. Simply use the value from cell  *(15,11)*  as the start of your loop and the value in cell *(15,12)* as the stop value

```css
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'defines some constants
    Const iYES_NO_COL = 8
    Const iOFFSET_COL = 11
    Const iSKIP_TO_COL = 12
    
    If Target.Count > 1 Then
    
        For Each cel In Target
               Call Worksheet_Change(cel)
               Next cel
        End If
    ElseIf Target.Count = 1 Then
        'im not sure what this does so i left it
        If Target.Column = 8 Then
           
           If LCase(Target.Value) = LCase(Target.Offset(, 3)) Then
           Cells(Target.Offset(, 4), 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
               Cells(Target.Offset(, 4), 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        
        End If
        
        If (Target.Column = iYES_NO_COL) Then
            '     takes the current row + the value in the offset cell
            my_start = Target.Row + Cells(Target.Row, iOFFSET_COL).Value
            
            '     takes the value from the SKIP_TO_COL
            my_stop = Cells(Target.Row, iSKIP_TO_COL).Value
        
            'target should be only one cell at this point, see if it
            'contains the word no
            If (StrComp(Trim(LCase(Target.Value)), "no") = 0) Then
            
                'hides all the rows between the start and stop value
                For i = my_start To mystop
                    Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Next
            ElseIf (StrComp(Trim(LCase(Target.Value)), "yes") = 0) Then
                
                'unhides all the rows between the start and stop value
                For i = my_start To mystop
                    Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = False
                Next
            End If
    End If

End Sub
```